# a point from ISO document: based on Anonymous Unions

Tags: c++, class, c++11, unions

Point from ISO C++ Standard: section 9.5, para 4, line 1:

```
      "A union for which objects or pointers are declared is not
       an anonymous union."
```

Example :

```
 struct X {
        union {
               int i;
               double d;
             } ;
        int f () { return i;}      
       };
   int main() { return 0; }
```

IAm expecting an error from this example according to the above point

but GCC,SUN compiler CC,EDG,etc are not showing error

iam expecting  this error// error : cannot directly access "i"

please ..conform above example program is correct are wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would make the union not anonymous:

```
struct X {
    union {
        int i;
        double d;
    } *p;
    int f () { return i;}      // !Nyet.
};
```

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 3):

To add to what Alf is saying, the purpose of the anonymous union language in the C++ spec is to allow scoping of the unions members. If you have a named union inside a struct:

```
struct X {
    union {
        int i;
        double d;
    } varname;
};
```

`i` is not a member of the struct X. `i` is a member of `varname`, which itself is a member of struct `X`.

However, if the union doesn't have a member variable declared, then `i` would have to be accessed directly as a member of `X`. This can only work if the union has no name (no variables are declared with the union definition). Such unions are called "anonymous unions".